# Font awesome fill only a quarter of an icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am creating a star review system and want to use font awesome to display the stars. However the difficulty im running into is my marketing team wants the stars to be able to display filled in 1/10th increments. Is there a way to achieve this?

I have found something like this: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/fontawesome/pen/GyjamK)

However this is just overlaying the half star. Is there a way to:

```
-webkit-text-fill: 1px black;
```

Comment: font awesome creates that using svg and path, so you cant do it

Comment: Here ya go: https://jsfiddle.net/vco9r2rt/3/

Comment: @Richard Thanks! please answer the question so i can give you credit!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates filling in a FontAwesome star using percentages: https://jsfiddle.net/vco9r2rt/3/

```
<!-- html -->
<span class="star fa fa-star"></span>

/* css */
.star {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.star:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f005";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #f80;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I was trying the same on with the flask icon. https://jsfiddle.net/hsjeevan/n1u9wjsL . How do I change the direction of the fill? The direction is currently top->bottom and want to change it to bottom->top. –