# psuedo-element in CSS is not showing on the page although the class is correct. This using React, CSS and a Font Awesome icon

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to make a component in React that uses Font Awesome to display a certain number of stars per product rating, including partial stars.

From this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118336/font-awesome-fill-only-a-quarter-of-an-icon) I saw that you can do this using `::after`, and I can see it works fine on jsfiddle. For example -

```
.star {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.star::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f005";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #f80;
}
```

However in my implementation only the base styles are showing, and not the ones on the psuedo-element. I can actually see the psuedo-element when I look in the Elements / Styles section of the developer console. However it's not having an effect visually and I've checked in multiple browsers.

Here's some more of my code for reference.

CSS

```
.star-100 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.star-100::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  /* content contains the unicode for the star shape */
  content: "\f005";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #f80;
}
```

I've also installed FontAwesome using this [method](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react) for React. Also the stars are showing initially fine it's just the styling afterwards that's not appearing right.

I originally had this with a single `:` instead of two as in the previous example I saw, I also updated the font-family to match what's in the current FontAwesome documentation and I didn't have it as a string previously which I've changed. I've also messed around with the order of things in the `::after` portion yet it's still not showing up on the page.

I'm expecting it to overwrite the original style with what's in the `::after` section to allow for showing partial stars based on the percentage as in the example previously. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vco9r2rt/3/) they linked to.

Instead I'm only seeing the initial styles displaying on the page. So only the "blank" star color I'm initializing it with.

[image: 5 greyed out star shapes]

Do you have any advice that could help please? Thanks!

Comment: The `.star` selector may be overriding the `.star-100` selector's rules if it comes after it in your CSS. Try making the star-100 selector more specific to ensure its rules get applied. You could do this by changing `.star-100::after` to `.star.star-100::after`

Comment: How do you map the rating score to applied styles?

Comment: @jla I tried that, it didn't work but thank you!

Comment: @Martin I'm using the FontAwesome React component to make the star, and I use a dynamic class name (set with a string template literal) when I call the component. Then the CSS applies based on the class name, so that's how I have them linked up.

If you want to know how I break the rating down so each star knows what percentage it should be that's a little bit of a longer question lol (though not that long)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the font family. I used this style sheet and it works fine-

https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css

Here is how I did it using the above stylesheet.

You can run the snippet-

```css
.star-100 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.star-100::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  /* content contains the unicode for the star shape */
  content: "\f005";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #f80;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="star-100 fa fa-star"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's helpful. From checking more closely in the packages I installed with their documentation it looks like by default it installs the latest version 6 which has [very different syntax for pseudo-elements](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/upgrade/pseudo-elements), and the link in their docs about "our provided CSS Custom Properties" doesn't go anywhere at the moment. I'll see about downgrading to version 5 locally which should hopefully help. Thanks again!

Comment: @MwaniN I tried using latest stylesheet from here and it works fine with it. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

Comment: thank you, did you also use the same 'Font Awesome 5 Free' as the font-family please? I think it might also be because I'm using it with it being installed locally as they recommend for [react](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/), I'm not sure if that makes this different somehow

Comment: @MwaniN Yes, same font-family. I just changed the script src to the newer one and it worked fine. You can check it by adding to the snippet here.

Comment: Thank you, I might need to try to do it with the HTML link somehow since it's not working with the downloaded/installed packages as they recommend to do for using it with React. Thank you for your help testing it and your recommendation!